# Python error - Unicode/Ascii problems with value pulled out of MySql database

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, ascii, docx

This has been asked a million times but every single thing I try hasn't worked and all are for slightly different issues.  I'm losing my mind over it!

I have a Python Script which pulls data from a MySql database - all works well.

**Database Information:**

- I believe the information in the database is correct. I am trying to parse multiple records into word documents - that is why I am not too bothered about accuracy - even if the bad characters are removed - that is fine.
- The Charset of the database is UTF-8 and the field I am working with is VarChar
- I am using mysql.connector python module to connect

However, I am getting errors and I've realised it's because of values with unicode in, such as this:

[image: Screenshot of entry in database]

The value of this item is "DOMAINoardroom".

I have tried:

```
    text = order[11].encode().decode("utf-8")
    text = order[11].encode("ascii", errors="ignore").decode()
    text = str(order[11].encode("utf8", errors="ignore"))
```

The latter does work however it outputs it as b'DOMAIN\x08oardroom' due to it being bytes

I can get it to accept the text by print(text) to the screen.  However when I try to output it to a word document (using the docx module), it produces an error:

```
table = document.add_table(rows=total_orders*2, cols=1)
row = table.rows[0].cells
row[0].text = row_text
```

ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters

I am not particularly fussy over how it handles the unicode, e.g. remove it if needed, but I just need it to parse without error.

Any thoughts or advice here?

Comment: @redrabbit29, it seems that value of item is not "DOMAINoardroom" according to the picture. It consists of \x08 which is a control byte that cannot be decoded using ascii or utf-8 standards as a character and only characters are required in XML format. That is what the error mean to say. I did ```string_data = str(byte_data,'utf-8')``` and on printng string_data, it printed :DOMAIoardroom, skipping N & \x08. You can try this if it helps you.

Comment: @JenilDave thank you for that - I got that working now which is good.  The secondary issue I have though is that I then can't add it to the word doc - using row[0].text = text.  Despite being able to print to screen and it appearing good.  The error I get is the same but for that line instead - "ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters"

Comment: The data is bad.  The string was likely originally inserted as the literal string "DOMAIN\boardroom" but `\b` is an escape code for a backspace, which is the control byte `\x08`. Printing the string executes the backspace, getting `DOMAIoardroom` like @JenilDave sees.

Comment: (Adding to Mark's Comment)  Double up the backslash if that is the character you needed:  `DOMAIN\\boardroom`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am a bit confused then how to resolve this.  The database contains about 70'000 entries - the vast majority are fine.  

I can get it to print to screen without error, but I can't get it to go into the word document without the b'mystring' being inserted into the page, even when I encode it as utf8.  

I will try to clean the code up to show you the issues, but each time I solve one issue, there's another problem.  I'm wondering if there's something I can do from within the MySQL database instead which may clean it up.

Comment: Thumbs up for ... losing my mind over it ... Should be simple like 
`a_strng = unicode_to_ascii(a_strng)`